# TFS Cancel Build/Release should also clean workspace

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Is there a possibility, when I cancel a TFS Build via Web, that an automatic cleanup will be done?
I have the problem, that everytime I cancel a build/release - the "workspace" will not cleaned. So that means only the task will ended.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be cleaned next time the job runs. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the source section of your build make sure you clean every time you build.  Please note this will slow down your build time if you have a lot of sources

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems you use on-premise TFS/DevOps Server, there is no default way to clean workspace when you cancel Build/Release.

You would need to add your own powershell script to clean the workspace in Build/Release Pipeline. An easy way is as @Daniel Mann mentioned, you can clean the workspace in your next build.

Comment: It's TFS not Service, there is no Microsoft Hosted.